# SQL Server :  INNER JOIN writes out things two times

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, inner-join

Here is my SQL query

```
select 
    tblUnderKategori.fldKategori, 
    tblUnderKategori.fldNavn,  
    tblUnderKategori.fldBillede, 
    tblKategori.fldId, 
    tblKategori.fldKategoriNavn 
from 
    tblUnderKategori
inner join 
    tblKategori on tblUnderKategori.fldKategori=2
```

And as you can see I need everything where my `fldKategori = 2`, and so it does, but it writes it out x2 times.

And here is my backend code for the place where it needs to be displayed

```
katFac objKat = new katFac();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {
        foreach (DataRow item in objKat.GetUnderkatByKat(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"])).Rows)
        {
            litUnderkategori.Text += item["fldNavn"].ToString() + "<br /><br />";
        }
    }
}
```

I just can't seeme to figure out the problem so anyone please help

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: I believe that you have duplicate rows... check for it first

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a karthesian product here as your join is missing the condition that actually joins the two tables together.
Try to use this:

```
select  
    tblUnderKategori.fldKategori,  
    tblUnderKategori.fldNavn,   
    tblUnderKategori.fldBillede,  
    tblKategori.fldId,  
    tblKategori.fldKategoriNavn  
from  
    tblUnderKategori 
        inner join tblKategori  
            on tblUnderKategori.fldKategori = tblKategori.fldId
where tblUnderKategori.fldKategori=2
```

This assumes that `tblUnderKategori.fldKategori` contains the ID of the parent category.

Answer (score 1):

A `JOIN` joins two tables, and you must provide the common column. If you also want to filter out certain values, add a `WHERE` clause afterwards. Also, you don't actually have to `SELECT` the fields used for matching and joining if you don't explicitly want to read them later on.

```
select 
   tblUnderKategori.fldNavn,  
   tblUnderKategori.fldBillede, 
   tblKategori.fldKategoriNavn
from tblUnderKategori join tblKategori
   on tblUnderKategori.fldKategori = tblKategori.fldId
where
   tblUnderKategori.fldKategori = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

ON clause specifies on which column that tables should be joined, condition should be included in WHERE clause. Try Something like this:

```
SELECT
   tblUnderKategori.fldKategori, 
   tblUnderKategori.fldNavn, 
   tblUnderKategori.fldBillede,
   tblKategori.fldId,        
   tblKategori.fldKategoriNavn    
FROM tblUnderKategori           
   INNER JOIN tblKategori    
   ON tblUnderKategori.[some key column] = tblKategori.[corresponding key column]        
WHERE tblUnderKategori.fldKategori=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You SQL statement is missing a field to `JOIN` the tables on.  It should be something like this:

```
select u.fldKategori, 
    u.fldNavn,  
    u.fldBillede, 
    k.fldId, 
    k.fldKategoriNavn 
from tblUnderKategori u
inner join tblKategori k
  on u.fldKategori = k.fldId
where u.fldKategori=2
```

Then you will apply your filter in the the `WHERE` clause.